# JSF: Custom component in tables not rendered as expected

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a suitable solution for the [custom component root-issue](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/cc-pitfalls-root-component/) in the meanwhile?

In short terms, the problem is that using custom components containing of both a **label and an input field** within a table like

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <jl:inputField value="#{testBean.value1}"/>
  <jl:inputField value="#{testBean.value2}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

... will be rendered within a single row.

A dirty solution would be to place the panelGrid within the component which will cause a rendering of a separate table for each input field. This is most likely the case cause there isn't a bottom-up but a top-down approach when parsing the code.

Do you have any other ideas how to handle this? Custom tags were mentioned in the discussion.

Comment: You can use facelet's tags or try use [TagExt](https://github.com/skybber/tagext)

Comment: I solved the Issue by using ui:composition instead